# Unhandled Rejection [TypeError, Cannot read property 'split' of undefined]

Tags: typescript, botpress

The error given below is causing BotPress v12.21.1 server to crash. It doesn't give any other details about the error. I was getting the same error in BotPress v12.14.1, but it wasn't crashing the server.

```
Launcher Unhandled Rejection [TypeError, Cannot read property 'split' of undefined]
STACK TRACE
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at C:\snapshot\build-windows\out\bp\core\telemetry\stats\sdk-stats.js
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at SDKStats.parseMethods (C:\snapshot\build-windows\out\bp\core\telemetry\stats\sdk-stats.js)
    at SDKStats.parseFile (C:\snapshot\build-windows\out\bp\core\telemetry\stats\sdk-stats.js)
```

After the BotPress server restarts twice, I'm getting this error.

```
Cluster Exceeded the maximum number of automatic server reboot (2). Set the "BP_MAX_SERVER_REBOOT" environment variable to change that
```

This error is resolved if I remove the code that uses **Knex** module.

```
const knex = require('knex')({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: 'postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname',
      pool: { min: 0, max: 10 },
      useNullAsDefault: false,
      log: {
        warn(message) {
          console.log(message)
        },
        error(message) {
          console.error(message)
        },
        deprecate(message) {
          console.log(message)
        },
        debug(message) {
          console.log(message)
        }
      }
    })
```

It's also resolved if I turn off **sendUsageStats**.

```
"sendUsageStats": true
```

But, both are part of business requirements and I can't use both of these workarounds. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: The issue was with Knex module. Somehow adding an await keyword before require('Knex') resolved the issue. But, I still couldn't understand why a require statement returns a promise. It would be great if someone could help me understand why. BotPress really needs to work on its stack trace more.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for behind a little bit late on this thread. I was browsing the PR from the botpress repo and one of the PR looks like you [issue](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/pull/5164) and another PR [here](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/issues/5158).

Probably I will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: this would be better as a comment as it doesn't really answer the question.  See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: You are right. sorry about that! I'm still learning stackoverflow. I didn't see the small `add comment` button. I really appreciated the link.